# ValueError at /accounts/login/ The view accounts.views.signinView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

accounts/views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm
from .models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout

def signupView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            signup_user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
            customer_group = Group.objects.get(name='Customer')
            customer_group.user_set.add(signup_user)
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form':form})

def signinView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('phoneshop:allProdCat')
            else:
                return redirect('signup')
        else:
            form = AuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, 'signin.html', {'form': form})

def signoutView(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('signin')
```

accounts/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from phoneshop import views
from .views import signupView, signinView, signoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', signupView, name='signup'),
    path('login/', signinView, name='signin'),
    path('logout/', signoutView, name='signout'),
]
```

main/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name ='phoneshop'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.allProdCat, name ='allProdCat'),
    path('<uuid:category_id>/', views.allProdCat, name='products_by_category'),
    path('<uuid:category_id>/<uuid:product_id>/', views.prod_detail, name='prod_detail'),
]
```

I can't seem to figure out why the return value is None. I believe the issue to be in the urls somewhere as I have an issue with redirection. I have the same error when trying to logout as well. I just can't seem to see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indented the `else:` part in the  `signinView` too much, as a result the `else` binds with `if form.is_valid():`, but you should bind this with `if request.method == 'POST'`. If you trigger this if the form is not valid, then there is no code to run when you make a *GET* request to that view. We however want in that case to construct a new form and render the tempate:

```
def signinView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('phoneshop:allProdCat')
            else:
                return redirect('signup')
    #   ↓ indent to the left.
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'signin.html', {'form': form})
```

---

> **Note**: Functions are normally written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, therefore it is
> advisable to rename your function to `signin_view`, not <s>`signinView`</s>.